# MySQL BIT type SET using quotes

Tags: mysql, bit

I have this query

```
UPDATE myTable SET f='MYVALUE' WHERE id=1
```

In which I can **ONLY** modify MYVALUE, nothing else.
Now, if `f` is any of these types:
`INT` `SMALLINT` `MEDIUMINT` `BIGINT` `TINYTEXT` `TEXT` `MEDIUMTEXT` `BIGTEXT` `ENUM('0','1')` `SET('0','1')` `TIME` `YEAR` and I got bored of writing them but... You get the point: ANY TYPE, it works.

If `f` is of type `BIT`, regardless of how many bits, then no, it doesn't let me. I was hoping to be able to do one of the following:

1. Set directly a binary number `f='10111'` : no.
2. Set a decimal value, hoping it would convert it `f='23'` : no.
3. Set an hex value, hoping it would convert it `f='0x23'` : no.
4. Use the correct syntax (albeit with the wrong quotes) `f='b'10111''` : no.
5. Escaping the quotes `f='b\'10111\''` : no.
6. Duplicating the quotes `f='b''10111'''` : no.

Yes, I know, I could simply write `f=b'10111'` but as said I cannot remove those quotes. I can only change that "value" parameter.
Is there a workaround? It works with any types, really... EXCEPT bits!!!

**To clarify**: it's like I can only use a function called setValue(value) and I have no control over the content. Let's say PHP

```
function setValue($v) {
  $sql = "UPDATE myTable SET f='$v' WHERE id=1"; 
  // execute $sql
}
```

Comment: as always use int in a size you need and use bit conversion to int so you save 3 itis 11000000

Comment: Given the rigid constraints you are apparently working under, I don't see how you can enter bit values.

Answer (score 0):

Use query parameters.

Here's a demo using MySQL text protocol prepared statements, but this would work with prepared statements in any programming language.

```
mysql> set @b = b'101';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare s from 'update mytable set f = ? where id = 1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute s using @b;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select id, bin(f) from mytable;
+----+--------+
| id | bin(f) |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 101    |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you, it's something I didn't know. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I can only provide MYVALUE parameter and the query cannot be changed, nor I can send other commands. I am looking for "what to put inside" the quotes so that it can be parsed as binary. And if it cannot be done, well, ok, but... :)

Comment: You would have to use characters whose encoding happens to match the bits you want to input. This will be very difficult, and it won't work anyway for any arbitrary value, because not every bit pattern you might want to input even corresponds to a character in the client character set. Basically, you'd have to become an expert with character sets.